# Solving linear systems with matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
   A= \begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & -1 \\
    -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
   B= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 \\
    2 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
   C= \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

How would I solve for X if AX+B=C? I know that A will become A inverse, but what happens to B? Does it become negative B?

Comment: Yes, first you should isolate $AX$ by subtracting $B$ from both sides: $AX=C-B$. Then you can multiply both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$ to get $A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}(C-B)$, i.e., $X=A^{-1}(C-B)$.

Comment: @kccu, thanks a lot. Also say for example, I have to find Y when               (Y + BC^T)^-1 = A , then how would you make Y the subject? Is it going to be Y^-1 = ABC^T ?

Comment: You have to work from the outside in. The outermost thing is the inverse, so undo that to get $(Y+BC^T)=A^{-1}$. Then subtract $BC^T$ from both sides to isolate $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The method is this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 1 \\
    3 & 0 & -1 \\
    -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}*
  X=
   \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -4 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

The inverse matrx of $A$ is: 
$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Then multiplicate RHS and LHS by $A^{-1}$ and you get:
$$X=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}*
   \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -4 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
After some calculation you get the solution:
$$X=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -3 \\
    -2 & 6 \\
    1 & -10 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, I got exactly that!